# How to dynamically append sections and use those to append other sections with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Straight to the point. I have a problem with `.append()` function. I need to append a section, containing datetime-local and a button to another section, which is visible.

This new appended button must append another section, containing the same elements, but WITH DIFFERENT IDs. First part of the code is working, but second doesn’t and I can’t get why. I know my code is elegant like an elephant, but...

Your help is appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 2;
  var wrapper = $(".input_1");
  var add_button = $(".add_1");

  var x = 1;

  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<section class="input_2">-.-.-<br/><input type="datetime-local"><a href="#" class="remove_1">Remove</a><br /> <button class="add_2">return</button> </section>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_1", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('section').remove();
    x--;
  })
});

//level 2
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields_2 = 2;
  var wrapper_2 = $(".input_2");
  var add_button_2 = $(".add_2");

  var x = 1;

  $(add_button_2).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields_2) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper_2).append('<section>-.-.-<br/><input type="datetime-local"><a href="#" class="remove_2">Remove</a><br /> <button class="add_3">return 2</button> </section>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper_2).on("click", ".remove_2", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('section').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="input_1">
  <input type="datetime-local"><br/>
  <button class="add_1">return to icu</button>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm sure what exactly not working.. Can you describe the steps we should do to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @MoshFeu when you click the button the new section appears. When you click the button in the new section the next section did not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delegates and find elements in event handler for dynamically added content, like it's for ".remove_1" in your code.

```js
//level 2
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields_2 = 2;
  var x = 1;

  $(document).on('click', '.add_2', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var wrapper_2 = $(".input_2");
    if (x < max_fields_2) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper_2).append('<section>-.-.-<br/><input type="datetime-local"><a href="#" class="remove_2">Remove</a><br /> <button class="add_3">return 2</button> </section>');
      $(wrapper_2).on("click", ".remove_2", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('section').remove();
        x--;
      })
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's becuase when `document.ready` you set `var wrapper_2 = $(".input_2");` but `$(".input_2")` is not existing yes, so it `undefined`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 2;
  var wrapper = $(".input_1");
  var add_button = $(".add_1");

  var x = 1;

  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<section class="input_2">-.-.-<br/><input type="datetime-local"><a href="#" class="remove_1">Remove</a><br /> <button class="add_2">return</button> </section>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_1", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('section').remove();
    x--;
  })
});

//level 2
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields_2 = 3;

  var x = 1;

  $('body').on('click', '.add_2', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields_2) {
      x++;
      $(".input_2").append('<section>-.-.-<br/><input type="datetime-local"><a href="#" class="remove_2">Remove</a><br /> <button class="add_3">return 2</button> </section>');
    }
  });

  $(".input_2").on("click", ".remove_2", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('section').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="input_1">
  <input type="datetime-local"><br/>
  <button class="add_1">return to icu</button>
</section>
```

Comment: But ".input_2" does not exist as well, so $(".input_2").on("click", ...) in your code won't work too. We need to find it dynamically, see code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

**happ coding :)**